# How to get day of week name from selected date month and year in Android?

Tags: java, android, date, android-datepicker, dayofweek

I tried the below code but it gives me the name of the day of week two days ago.

```
  DatePicker picker;
  int date = picker.DayOfMonth;
  int month = (picker.Month + 1);//month is 0 based
  int year = picker.Year;

  SimpleDateFormat simpledateformat = new SimpleDateFormat("EEE");
  Date dt = new Date(year, month, date);
```

Comment: Did you try this String dayOfTheWeek = (String) android.text.format.DateFormat.format("EEEE", date); you need to pass the date object and it will do the rest, Output: Thursday

Comment: Codewise there is nothing wrong with the use of SimpleFormatter. The thing is, if you are using the date constructor as shown in the example, both month and date parameters are 0 based

Comment: One thing to note though, in 'Date(year, month, date)' , month parameter is also 0-based but you're using 'int month = (picker.Month + 1);. You should try 'int month = picker.Month;

Comment: After looking at the answers all I can say is that some developers are making some others lazy. Care to explain the answers guys? :(

Comment: Week name? Do you mean day-of-week?

Comment: As an aside consider throwing away the long outmoded and notoriously troublesome `SimpleDateFormat` and friends, and adding [ThreeTenABP](https://github.com/JakeWharton/ThreeTenABP) to your Android project in order to use `java.time`, the modern Java date and time API. It is so much nicer to work with.

Comment: Your code, is it compilable Java code? The way I read [the DatePicker documentation](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/DatePicker.html) it hasn’t got fields `DayOfMonth`, `Month` and `Year` (and the initial capital letters disagree with Java naming conventions).

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please search and research before asking (see [How do I ask a good question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)) For the benefit of yourself and everyone: you will get a good answer faster, and we will have fewer duplicate questions lying around.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

First  convert your Date in to specific Date format  using [**`SimpleDateFormat`**](https://developer.android.com/reference/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html)

Use  `SimpleDateFormat simpleDateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("EEEE");` to get Day name in week

WHERE  **`EEEE`** ->    Day name in week

**SAMPLE CODE**

```
 SimpleDateFormat inFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("dd-MM-yyyy");
 try {
       Date myDate = inFormat.parse(date+"-"+month+"-"+year);
       SimpleDateFormat simpleDateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("EEEE");
       String dayName=simpleDateFormat.format(myDate);
 } catch (ParseException e) {
     e.printStackTrace();
}
```

Comment: Thanks @Nilesh Rathod ,convert your Date in to specific Date format solved the problem.

Comment: Hand formatting and them parsing back. That’s overcomplicating things. And you’re still using the long outdated and notoriously troublesome `SimpleDateFormat` class.

Answer (score 1):

```
SimpleDateFormat dateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("EEE", Locale.US); 
String asWeek = dateFormat.format(dt);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
    DateTimeFormatter dayOfWeekFormatter 
            = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("EEE", Locale.ENGLISH);
    LocalDate date = LocalDate.of(
            picker.getYear(), picker.getMonth(), picker.getDayOfMonth());
    System.out.println(date.format(dayOfWeekFormatter));
```

Picking 2018-04-09 this printed

> Mon

I am using and recommending `java.time`, the modern Java date and time API. The `Date` class is long outdated, and you are using a deprecated constructor. It was deprecated because it works unreliably across time zones, so you shouldn’t. `SimpleDateFormat` is not only outdated, it is also notoriously troublesome. I recommend you avoid those classes altogether. The modern API is so much nicer to work with.

### What went wrong in your code?

You’ve got two bugs apart from using the deprecated `Date` constructor and the outdated classes:

1. It’s the `Date`’s month that is 0-based (not that of `DatePicker`), so you need to subtract 1, not add 1 (or maybe they are both 0-based??).
2. The deprecated `Date` constructor’s year is “1900-based”. This may have seemed a good idea when the class was designed in the 1990’s: you could just specify 95 to get 1995. When you pass 2018 to the constructor, you get year 3918. That’s right. :-(

### Question: Can I use java.time on Android?

Yes, `java.time` works nicely on older and newer Android devices. It just requires at least Java **6**.

- In Java 8 and later and on newer Android devices (from API level 26, I’m told) the modern API comes built-in.
- In Java 6 and 7 get the ThreeTen Backport, the backport of the new classes (ThreeTen for JSR 310; see the links at the bottom).
- On (older) Android use the Android edition of ThreeTen Backport. It’s called ThreeTenABP. And make sure you import the date and time classes from `org.threeten.bp` with subpackages.

### Links

- [Oracle tutorial: Date Time](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/datetime/) explaining how to use `java.time`.
- [Java Specification Request (JSR) 310](https://jcp.org/en/jsr/detail?id=310), where `java.time` was first described.
- [ThreeTen Backport project](http://www.threeten.org/threetenbp/), the backport of `java.time`to Java 6 and 7 (ThreeTen for JSR-310).
- [ThreeTenABP](https://github.com/JakeWharton/ThreeTenABP), Android edition of ThreeTen Backport
- [Question: How to use ThreeTenABP in Android Project](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38922754/how-to-use-threetenabp-in-android-project), with a very thorough explanation.

Comment: correct me if i'm wrong **`DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern`** will required **`@RequiresApi(api = Build.VERSION_CODES.O)`** this is just for information

Comment: I suspect you’ve been looking at `java.time.format.DateTimeFormatter`, @NileshRathod. I tried to explain that you should use `org.threeten.bp.format.DateTimeFormatter`.  Try it, it shouldn’t require any high API level. `Build.VERSION_CODES.O` seems to agree with the level 26 I mentioned for the built-in classes like `java.time.format.DateTimeFormatter`.

Answer (score 0):

`Calendar calendar = Calendar.getInstance();
DateFormat date4= new SimpleDateFormat("EEEE", Locale.getDefault());
        String localTime4 = date4.format(calendar.getTime());`

Simple and easy way
just use this