# Simple date format day of week displays same day

Tags: java, android, date, simpledateformat, dayofweek

I'm having issues with the below code displays Thursday as the dayOfTheWeek regardless of the date. Any ideas where I've gone wrong with this?

```java
public void CreatePlan() {
    editPlanName = findViewById(R.id.editPlanName);
    String plan_name = editPlanName.getText().toString();
    DatabaseManager db;
    int day = datepicker.getDayOfMonth();
    int month = datepicker.getMonth();
    int year = datepicker.getYear();
    SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("EEEE");
    Integer d_name = day;
    Integer plan_recipe = 0;
    Log.d("Date", String.valueOf(d_name));
    String dayOfTheWeek = sdf.format(d_name);
    String date = day + "/" + month + "/" +year;
    db = new DatabaseManager(getApplicationContext());
    Log.d("Recipe name", recipe_name);
    db.createPlanRecipe(d_name, date, dayOfTheWeek, recipe_name);
    db.createPlan(plan_name, plan_recipe);
}
```

Comment: As an aside consider throwing away the long outmoded and notoriously troublesome `SimpleDateFormat` and friends. See if you either can use [desugaring](https://developer.android.com/studio/write/java8-support-table) or add [ThreeTenABP](https://github.com/JakeWharton/ThreeTenABP) to your Android project, in order to use java.time, the modern Java date and time API. It is so much nicer to work with.

Answer (score 0):

You have to create `Date` from your `datepicker`, then format it to find day like below:

```
  int day = datePicker.getDayOfMonth();
  int month = datePicker.getMonth();
  int year =  datePicker.getYear();

  Calendar calendar = Calendar.getInstance();
  calendar.set(year, month - 1, day);

  SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("EEEE");
  dayOfTheWeek = sdf.format(calendar.getTime());
```

Comment: It will give you an incorrect result. In order to get the correct result, you need to use `calendar.set(year, month-1, day)` as `java.util` date is based on `0` as January.

Comment: Yes, that's correct, month in java date starts from 0.

Answer (score 0):

> … Any ideas where I've gone wrong with this?

`day` in your program is the day of the month from 1 to 31. Therefore `d_name` holds this number too.

Your `SimpleDateFormat` accepts formatting a number as a date and time expecting a count of milliseconds since the epoch of January 1, 1970 at 00:00 in UTC. So it will always format a date and time within the first 31 milliseconds after the epoch. Depending on your time zone the point in time that you format falls either on Wednesday, December 31, 1969 or on Thursday, January 1, 1970. So you will either always get Wednesday or always Thursday.

`SimpleDateFormat.format(Object)` accepts either a `Date` or a `Number`. Since `Integer` is a subclass of `Number`, it works as described.

The `SimpleDateFormat` class is notoriously troublesome, you have seen but a small corner of the problems that people often have with it. The `Calendar` class used in one other answer is poorly designed too. Both are long outdated. I suggest you look into [java.time, the modern Java date and time API](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/datetime/) instead.

Further link: [My answer to another question about getting the day of week from an Android date picker](https://stackoverflow.com/a/49730689/5772882).

Answer (score 0):

You are getting the value of the day-of-the-month, the month and the year in the following lines of code but you are not setting these values into the `Calendar` object which is supposed to give you other information (e.g. the day-of-week) by processing these values:

```
int day = datepicker.getDayOfMonth();
int month = datepicker.getMonth();
int year = datepicker.getYear();
```

So, before you try to get any other information from the `Calendar` object, set these values to the object as shown below:

```
// Set the picked values into an instance of Calendar
Calendar calendar = Calendar.getInstance();
calendar.clear();// Make sure to call this to reset all fields
calendar.set(year, month - 1, day);// Make sure to decrease month by 1
```

Now, your rest of code will work as you are expecting e.g. let's say you select `4` as the day-of-the-month, `10` as the month, and `2020` as the year, the following code will give you `Sunday` as the day-of-the-week.

```
import java.text.SimpleDateFormat;
import java.util.Calendar;

public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        int day = 4;
        int month = 10;
        int year = 2020;

        // Set the picked values into an instance of Calendar
        Calendar calendar = Calendar.getInstance();
        calendar.clear();// Make sure to call this to reset all fields
        calendar.set(year, month - 1, day);// Make sure to decrease month by 1
        System.out.println(calendar.getTime());

        // Your desired format
        SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("EEEE");

        // The day-of-the-week for the specified date
        String dayOfTheWeek = sdf.format(calendar.getTime());
        System.out.println(dayOfTheWeek);
    }
}
```

**Output:**

```
Sun Oct 04 00:00:00 BST 2020
Sunday
```

Note that I have decreased the month (picked from the date-picker) by `1` because `java.util` date-time API is based on `0` as the month of `January`.

### A piece of advice:

I recommend you switch from the outdated and error-prone `java.util` date-time API and `SimpleDateFormat` to the [modern](https://www.oracle.com/technical-resources/articles/java/jf14-date-time.html) `java.time` date-time API and the corresponding formatting API (from the package, `java.time.format`). Learn more about the modern date-time API from **[Trail: Date Time](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/datetime/index.html)**.

If your Android API level is still not compliant with Java-8, check [Java 8+ APIs available through desugaring](https://developer.android.com/studio/write/java8-support-table) and [How to use ThreeTenABP in Android Project](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38922754/how-to-use-threetenabp-in-android-project).

**By using the modern date-time API:**

```
import java.time.LocalDate;
import java.time.format.TextStyle;
import java.util.Locale;

public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        int dayOfMonth = 4;
        int month = 10;
        int year = 2020;

        // Instantiate a LocalDate object using the picked values
        LocalDate date = LocalDate.of(year, month, dayOfMonth);

        // The day-of-the-week for the specified date
        String dayOfTheWeek = date.getDayOfWeek().getDisplayName(TextStyle.FULL, Locale.ENGLISH);
        System.out.println(dayOfTheWeek);
    }
}
```

**Output:**

```
Sunday
```